# How to apply `yasnippets` only for keywords at the beginning of the line?

Tags: python, yasnippet

I am using Python but some pre-defineted snippets. I was wondering is it possible to apply them if the `keyword` is the first word.

`if` and `[TAB]` converted into `if cond:`. I want this behaviour if the keyword is the beginning of the line as first word.

---

Let's assume if I type `if` inside a double quotes `"`...if`[curoser]`...`"` and press `TAB`, or `object.if[TAB]`, then the snippet still applied, which I don't want.

Example cursor is right next to `if` and I press `TAB`

```
print("if")
         ^
```

=> Converted into following piece of code, which I don't want:

```
print("if cond:

")
```

---

or `object.if` TAB converted into

```
object.if cond:
```

Comment: @lawlist I get confust how to apply those solution to all the native/local snippets. Should I manuall change them one by one? or which changes should I make to my `.emacs` file

Comment: When the need arises, I personally use a combination of `wgrep` and `multiple-cursors` to make changes to multiple files in one fell swoop.  I don't know whether there is another solution beyond the linked proposed duplicate thread cited above.  You may or may not want to change multiple files given your particular needs ... you could start off by modifying just the snippets that should always activate only at the beginning of the line ...

Comment: Do you use ```doom-snippets```? if yes you may need some small configuration to work correctly in non-doom emacs.

Comment: No I am not using `doom-snippets`. Please note that I am using `GNU Emacs 26.3` terminal along with `yasnippet-classic-snippets` and `yasnippet-snippets`. Those exists under `/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/python-mode` and I have my local snippets under `~/.emacs.d/snippets/python-mode`. I get confused where should I manually change each snippet adding `# condition: (and (looking-back` to each snippet?

Comment: "*Optionally, if the file contains a line of `# --`, the lines above it count as comments, some of which can be directives (or meta data). Snippet directives look like `# property: value` and tweak certain snippets properties described below. If no `# --` is found, the whole file is considered the snippet template.*"  If you have not already read the tutorial, consider doing so:  https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#org5e87ae3  Add your `# condition:  ...` anywhere above the line `# --` in the snippet file.  If there is no `# --`, then add that below the comments.

Comment: @lawlist `# condition: (looking-back "^f" nil)` only applies if `f` at the beginnig of the line. Can we also do something like allow `<white-space>f` too? like if there is tab or space before `f` still snippet could be applied. But prevent if its in between a string like `"f"`

Comment: Perhaps you could try a regexp like `"^[\s\t]?+f"` as the first argument to `looking-back`.   The `\s` in brackets is a space.  The `\t` in brackets is a tab.  The `?` means that what is in brackets may or may not be present in what is being matched.  The `+` means that there may be more than one space and/or more than one tab.